# Auto Updating Winform Application Used Over Remote Desktop

Tags: c#, remote-desktop

We have an app we wrote deployed onto our terminal servers at work, and keeping it up-to-date is a bit of a pain.

What update mechanisms do people use for app on terminal servers? At the moment we manually copy the new exe + dependencies on witch is just rubbish.

I'm a bit concerned about files being locked by users when trying to update, i cant really just kill the process in case someone is in the middle of doing something. We would like to be able to handle the odd fat client update as well.

Ideally we'd plug something into teamcity/octopus but are open to suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Create a script that copies the exe file to a user specific temp folder, then launches the copied exe. To make the script more efficient, you can have it check the dates of the files. If they are different, then you copy the file over the old one located in the temp folder, else you just launch it.